# Relacionamento entre entidades

Tags: java, hibernate

Não estou conseguindo fazer a deleção do objeto selecionado.

Tenho duas classes, `Autor` e `Livro`, exemplo básico de funcionamento, para aprender o uso de Java Server Faces, até aqui tudo bem, funcionamento e etc. O problema é que na relação @ManyToMany, quando chamada a função pra excluir o registro, tanto, de autor e de livro, lança uma exceção de violação de constraint.

Segue a parte necessária para avaliação:

**Modelo de Autor**

```
@Entity
public class Autor implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "autor_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="autores")
    private List<Livro> livros;

    //Demais campos, getters e setters
}
```

**Modelo de Livro**

```
@Entity
public class Livro implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "livro_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "livro_autor", joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "livro_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "autor_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private List<Autor> autores = new ArrayList<Autor>();

    //Demais campos, getters e setters
}
```

**Bean Autor**

```
@ManagedBean
public class AutorBean {

    private Autor autor = new Autor();

    public void removeAutor(Autor autor){
        new DAO<Autor>(Autor.class).remove(autor);
    }

    //Demais métodos omitidos
}
```

**Bean Livro**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class LivroBean implements Serializable {

    private Livro livro = new Livro();
    private Integer autorId;
    public void removeLivro(Livro atualLivro){
        new DAO<Livro>(Livro.class).remove(atualLivro);     
    }

    //Demais métodos omitidos
}
```

**DAO**

```
public class DAO<T> {

    private final Class<T> classe;

    public DAO(Class<T> classe) {
        this.classe = classe;
    }

    public void remove(T t) {
        EntityManager em = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(em.merge(t));

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }
}
```

A relação cria uma terceira tabela, esperado, com o nome livro_autor. Ao excluir, lança esse erro:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`banco`.`livro_autor`, CONSTRAINT `FK33E9E1BAF971CF8` FOREIGN KEY (`autor_id`) REFERENCES `autor` (`autor_id`))
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
```

Se necessário alguma outra parte do código, só pedir. Os métodos omitidos são básicos, outros campos dos modelos, persistência, no caso do DAO, etc, tudo que não achei que acrescentasse algo na questão.

**EDIÇÃO**

Consegui fazer com que o campo do livro fosse excluído, o que está acontecendo agora é que se existir um livro para um dado autor, o autor não pode ser excluído, se não existe nenhum livro vinculado, o autor pode ser excluido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido.
Após colocar a pergunta aqui, o programa executou a função de exclusão de `livro`, o que não havia acontecido **antes** de publicar a pergunta *(sigh)*. Mesmo assim, a função de exclusão de `autor` estava dando o mesmo erro.
Tentei colocar:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "livro_autor", joinColumns = { 
    @JoinColumn(name = "livro_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { 
    @JoinColumn(name = "autor_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
private List<Autor> autores = new ArrayList<Autor>();
```

...o que tambem não funcionou.

Tentei passar o Cascade para a entidade do `Autor`, ficando assim:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="autores", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Livro> livros;
```

Não funcionou, mas ao alterar `CascadeType.ALL` para `CascadeType.REMOVE` funciona.

O erro dissecado seria que não podia excluir um livro que tinha livro vinculado na tabela `livro_autor`, e utilizando o CascadeType.REMOVE, toda a vez que eu removo um autor, o Hibernate remove automaticamente seus livros vinculados, o que me é esperado.